# How can I pass config parameters to the scripts I load?

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

Some JavaScript libraries pass config parameters to the script at load time.

For example:

in dojo (async mode):

```
<script src="dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with firebug lite (#startOpened opens the debugger at start):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='firebug-lite.js#startOpened'></script>
```

How does this work? How does the script collect the config parameters? Are there any limitations to this technique?